# Queue of Strings in C

Tags: c, string

I am trying to edit this program. Right now the users enters symbols and I want to make it work with Strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    char data;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct queue
{
    struct Node *top;
    struct Node *bottom;
}*q;

void Write(char x)
{
    struct Node *ptr=malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    ptr->data=x;
    ptr->next=NULL;
    if (q->top==NULL && q->bottom==NULL)
    {
        q->top=q->bottom=ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        q->top->next=ptr;
        q->top=ptr;
    }
}

char Read ()
{
    if(q->bottom==NULL)     
    {
        printf("Empty QUEUE!");
        return 0;
    }
    struct Node *ptr=malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    ptr=q->bottom;
    if(q->top==q->bottom)
    {
        q->top=NULL;
    }
    q->bottom=q->bottom->next;
    char x=ptr->data;
    free(ptr);
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    q= malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
    q->top=q->bottom=NULL;
    char ch='a';
    printf("NOTE: To stop the entry, please enter 'q'!\n\n Enter a String: \n");
    while(ch!='q')
    {
        scanf("%c",&ch);
        Write(ch);
    }
    printf("\nThe entered String:\n\n");
    while(q->bottom!=NULL)
    {
        ch=Read();
        printf("%c",ch);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    system("PAUSE"); 
    return 0;
}
```

So I am editing it like this (the code below) and I get error "[Error] incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[10]' from type 'char *'"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    char data[10];
    struct Node *next;
};

struct queue
{
    struct Node *top;
    struct Node *bottom;
}*q;

void Write(char x[10])
{
    struct Node *ptr=malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    ptr->data=x;
    ptr->next=NULL;
    if (q->top==NULL && q->bottom==NULL)
    {
        q->top=q->bottom=ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        q->top->next=ptr;
        q->top=ptr;
    }
}

char Read ()
{
    if(q->bottom==NULL)     
    {
        printf("Empty QUEUE!");
        return 0;
    }

    struct Node *ptr=malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    ptr=q->bottom;
    if(q->top==q->bottom)
    {
        q->top=NULL;
    }
    q->bottom=q->bottom->next;
    char x=ptr->data;
    free(ptr);
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    q= malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
    q->top=q->bottom=NULL;
    char ch][10]='a';
    printf("NOTE: To stop the entry, please enter 'q'!\n\n Enter a String: \n");
    while(ch!='q')
    {
        scanf("%c",&ch);
        Write(ch);
    }
    printf("\nThe entered String:\n\n");
    while(q->bottom!=NULL)
    {
        ch=Read();
        printf("%c",ch);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    system("PAUSE"); 
    return 0;
}
```

I can't solve this problem, so I would love to get some help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign to an array, but you can *copy* to it.

To copy a string use [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy):

```
strcpy(ptr->data, x);
```

Or since you have a limited array, maybe use [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy):

```
strncpy(ptr->data, x, sizeof(ptr->data) - 1);
ptr->data[sizeof(ptr->data) - 1] = '\0';
```

For `strncpy` it will not add the terminating `'\0'` character if the source is equal or longer than the specified length, so we have to make sure that the string is properly terminated.